# Quantum Field Theory and Lie Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, soft-question, education, group-theory, lie-algebra

I am reading Vol.1 of "The Quantum Theory Of Fields" by S. Weinberg. However I have come to a halt when connected [Lie groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) were introduced. I have solid knowledge in elementary group theory and general topology. I will now turn to studying Lie groups and algebras, and my question is:

1. What parts should I focus on?
2. What can I skip?
3. When is it "safe" to stop, and go back to the physics?

Comment: Hi Dror. Advices on how to study fits poorly on Phys.SE because they tend to be _primarily opinion-based._ I'm closing this question as a _duplicate,_ not because it is necessarily an exact duplicate, but to point in the right direction.

Comment: Opinion is kind of what I'm looking for here, anyways. But I understand.